# How to use RegEx to set up a new alphabet in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have download an RSS file and saved as `city.txt`.

Then I have to grab the date from the `<lastBuildDate>` tag.

The date is in the format: `Fri,28 Aug 2020` and then I have to translate the day and month  all using RegEx.

I have managed to get the date but I have problem changing the date and month after I have found it.

Do I have to use `re.sub`?

My code:

```
import re
with open('city.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    txt = f.read()
    tag_pattern =r'<''lastBuildDate'r'\b[^>]*>(.*?)</''lastBuildDate'r'>'
    found = re.findall(tag_pattern, txt, re.I)
    found = list(set(found))
    for f in found :print('\t\t', f)
```

Comment: You might be able to feed the English date into `datetime.strptime()` and then [re-output it in your language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985505/locale-date-formatting-in-python). But otherwise, `re.sub()` seems like the correct method if you're being forced to use regex - after all, you only need to translate the days of the week and names of the months, right?

Comment: We could help if you  better if you add how/what are ou trying to tanslate into..also for fun worth a read. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code based on your requirements, please give it a try.

**Code**

```py
import re
import locale
import datetime
with open('city.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    txt = f.read()
    tag_pattern =r'<''lastBuildDate'r'\b[^>]*>(.*?)</''lastBuildDate'r'>'
    found = re.findall(tag_pattern, txt, re.I)
    found = list(set(found))
    for f in found :
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "en")
        temp=datetime.datetime.strptime(f, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "el-GR")
        print(temp.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

**Sample input**

```xml
<lastBuildDate>Fri, 28 Jan 2020 13:32:12 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<lastBuildDate>Sun, 27 Feb 2020 15:36:53 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<lastBuildDate>Mon, 26 Aug 2020 16:30:43 GMT</lastBuildDate>
```

**Ouput**

```
Ôåô, 26 Áõã 2020 16:30:43
Ðåì, 27 Öåâ 2020 15:36:53
Ôñé, 28 Éáí 2020 13:32:12
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite it is really not recommended to parse XML content with regexes, your question is actually about date translations.

One approach is to [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1912434/4375327) the XML content of your RSS file retrieve the text value of the node `<lastBuildDate>`, then you can [parse it](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/) and get the value as a datetime object. with [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) of `datetime` package.

The sample below shows of you how to get a `datetime` objet from a `string`:

```
import datetime

# date_time_str contains the date string as formatted in your RSS
date_time_str = 'Fri,28 Aug 2020'
# date_time_obj contains the parsed value (formatted as '%a,%d %b %Y')
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%a,%d %b %Y')
```

Then you just have to retrieve the wanted datetime elements as integer. You can display those values in the current locale with the [calendar module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36341648/4375327) if it matches your language. Otherwise, a bit more tricky, you can [play with TimeEncoding and month_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13037425/4375327). (Of course you can write your own translation system.)

Comment: Thanks.
i dont really need to change the format. but
the language.
it looks like this:Fri, 28 Aug 2020 17:36:59 GMT
and i have to make it look like this Παρ,28 Αυγ 2020 17¨36 GMT

Comment: @marvin Yeah, actually it's not about to _change_ the format, but to _parse_ it. What you want is to extract date parts to translate them. This is what this approach is meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locale` in python to display date in Greek or any local language.
Please refer below code, and refer [this](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-LCID/%5bMS-LCID%5d.pdf) windows documentation for more locale string options.

```py
import datetime
import locale

input = 'Fri, 28 Aug 2020 17:36:59 GMT'
date_parsed = datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "el-CY")
print(date_parsed.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

prints

```
Ðáñ, 28 Áýã 2020 17:36:59
```